# Running Azure Function in AKS with Workload Identity and Eventhub Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks, workload-identity, eventhub

I am trying to run azure function in Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS) with eventhub trigger and workload identity. I was able to run the function successfully in AKS with managed identity, now I want to try workload identity with same function, I tried to find some documentation but could not find anything. I deployed the function with credentials as `workloadidentity` and checked the errors in pod logs to see what happens, I saw error saying "tenantId, clientId and tokenFilePath" is missing. I added environment variables like

```
EventHubConnection__clientId: ***
EventHubConnection__credential: workloadidentity
EventHubConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace: ***
EventHubConnection__tenantId: ***
EventHubConnection__tokenFilePath:  /var/run/secrets/azure/tokens/azure-identity-token
```

After that I saw error in logs saying `/var/run/secrets/azure/tokens/azure-identity-token` path not found. I checked in bash if this path exists but it did not, but I saw path `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` so I changed token file path to that.

After adding this I am getting this error.

```
StatusCode: 401 
ResponseBody: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70023: External OIDC Provider token must have a lifetime of less than or equal to 1.01:00:00. Token issued at 1711596573. Token expires on 1743132573. Trace ID: **** Correlation ID: **** Timestamp: 2024-03-28 03:37:57Z","error_codes":[70023],"timestamp":"2024-03-28 03:37:57Z","trace_id":"****","correlation_id":"****","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=70023"}
```

Deployment file has following

```
labels:
  azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
```

and

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: <service-account-name>
```

I could not find any documentation that could help me on my journey.

Comment: The error message you are seeing indicates that the token issued by the external OIDC provider has a lifetime greater than 1.01 hours. You may need to adjust the token lifetime to resolve this issue.

Comment: check these docs -   [Deploy and configure workload identity on an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-deploy-cluster#deploy-and-configure-workload-identity-on-an-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-cluster)
-   [Tutorial: Use a workload identity with an application on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/tutorial-kubernetes-workload-identity#tutorial-use-a-workload-identity-with-an-application-on-azure-kubernetes-service-aks)